# If $\angle CMP=90^{\circ}$, find $x$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

> Let $ABC$ an equilateral triangle, $M \in [CA]$, $N\in [AB]$, $P\in [BC]$ s.t $\angle CBM=x, \angle AMN=2x$ and angle $ \angle BNP=3x$. If $\angle CMP=90^{\circ}$, find $x$.

I tried a trigonometric solution as below but I am stuck. I noticed that $\triangle BNM$ is isosceles and I think that $x=15^{\circ}.$

[image]

Comment: You wrote that $P\in [AC]$, but $P$ is on $BC$ in your diagram instead. I assume it's a typo, but please confirm that.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I believe it's a typo, otherwise $\angle CMP$ cannot be $90^\circ$.

Comment: By considering $1=\frac{BN}{NP} \times \frac{NP}{MN}$ and the law of sine you can get: $$\frac{\sin (60+3x)}{\sin 60} \times \frac{\sin(90-2x)}{\sin (3x+30)}=1,$$ whose answer is $15^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution of the problem, showing the *uniqueness* of $x$ between $0^\circ$ and $30^\circ$ with the given property, then using the OP guess $x=15^\circ$, and showing this guess.

---

For the uniqueness, consider the points $M,N,P_1,P_2$ defined as in the picture, seen as functions of $x$.

[image: using analysis to show uniqueness of a point with given property in a geometric context]

Consider the segments $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ oriented as given by the vectors
$\vec{BC}$,
$\vec{CA}$,
$\vec{AB}$, and extend them to axes of coordinates for the corresponding lines, so that these segments are of (oriented) length one.
Consider the points $M,N,P_1,P_2$ on the sides of $\Delta ABC$, i.e. on these axes as in the picture, to be defined by the following conditions as functions of $x$,

- $M=M(x)$ with $\widehat{MBC}=x$,
  then
  $N=N(x)$ with $\widehat{NMA}=2x$,
  then
  $P_1=P_1(x)$ with $\widehat{P_1NB}=2x$,
  and
- $P_2=P_2(x)$ with $\widehat{P_2MC}=90^\circ$.

Then the functions $M,N,P_1$ are increasing, and $P_2$ decreasing.
In particular, $(P_1-P_2(x)=P_1(x)-P_2(x)$, with minus operation taken from the axis $\vec{BC}$, is an increasing continuous function, and
$(P_1-P_2)(0^\circ)=B-C=0-1=-1$,
$(P_1-P_2)(30^\circ)=C-B=1-0=+1$, so there exists a unique argument $x$ between $0^\circ$ and $30^\circ$ with $P_1(x)=P_2(x)$.

---

It is easy to show that $x=15^\circ$ verifies $P_1(x)=P_2(x)$.
This is so, since for this $x$ the triangle $\Delta BMN$ is right and isosceles, and $NP_1\perp BM$ becomes the perpendicular bisector of $BM$. Thus $\widehat{P_1BM}=\widehat{P_1MB}=x=15^\circ$, making $\widehat{CP_1M}=2x=30^\circ$, i.e. $P_1M\perp AC$, and thus $P_1=P_2$.

$\square$